# Putting $n$ balls into n-1 cells such that no cell is empty

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

> Suppose that $n$ identical balls are placed into $n − 1$ distinct boxes such that each distinguishable arrangement is equally likely. Find the probability that no box remains empty.

My answer is
$$ \frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{(n-1)^n} $$
where the denominator is the total number of ways of putting $n$ balls in $n-1$ cells and the numerator is the number of ways $1$ ball can be put into $n-1$ boxes and then the remaining $n-1$ balls are put into $n-1$ boxes in $(n-1)!$ number of ways.

Is this correct? If not, why? The correct answer for this seems to be
$$ \frac{n-1}{\binom{2n-2}{n}}.$$

Comment: I've tried to format your question using MathJax, but I had difficulty understanding the last displayed equation (it doesn't make sense as you wrote it, and I did my best to interpret what you wrote).

Comment: Please use MathJax to typeset your expressions.  Surround inline math with single dollar signs, and surround display math with double dollar signs.  For instance, `$\frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{(n-1)^n}$` produces $\frac{(n-1)(n-1)!}{(n-1)^n}$.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for more tips.

Comment: The number of ways of putting $n$ **distinct** balls is $(n-1)$ distinct boxes is $(n-1)^n$, but this problem is for **identical** balls. This is the mistake in your solution. To count placements of identical balls into distinct boxes, you can use stars and bars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have no box empty, you first put one ball in each box. Since the balls are identical so there is only one way of doing this. Now you are left with one ball and that can go to any of the $n-1$ boxes. So there are $n-1$ ways to achieve this (so called *favorable* ways).

Now for the total number of ways to distribute the $n$ balls into $n-1$ boxes we let $x_i$ be the number of balls in the $i-$th box. So we want to find the number of non-negative ($x_i \geq 0 $) integer solutions to the following equation:
$$x_1+x_2+\dotsb+x_{n-1}=n.$$
Read about [stars & bars problem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) to find the answer to this.

Answer (score 1):

If no box is empty, one box must contain $2$ balls, and each of the other boxes must contain $1$ ball. There are $n-1$ ways to choose the box that gets $2$ balls, and after that everything is completely determined, so there are just $n-1$ distinguishable arrangements of the balls that have no empty box.

The remainder of the problem is counting all of the possible arrangements. That is a basic [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem, and the linked Wikipedia article has a decent explanation. Here you want **Theorem two**; the $k$ of the theorem is your $n-1$, and the $n$ of the theorem is your $n$, so the number of arrangements is

$$\binom{n+(n-1)-1}{n}=\binom{2n-2}n\;.$$